# Cutting data via sql query

Tags: sql

I want to write similar to "click for more".

I cant remember this tech. I could via sql query.
I want to select data's first 30 character.

How?

Comment: SUBSTRING(data,1,30) works in most SQL dialects.   What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: select substring(example,1,50) as cutted FROM table. is this true?

Comment: Yep, looks like you got a solution

Comment: You'd probably also want to check the length of the string in order to know if there are any more characters to retrieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every SQL flavor I've worked with has a substring function:

[Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions169.htm#i87066), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-string.html), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, 30) FROM table;
```

[SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, 30) FROM table;
```

---

Alternatively, you can make use of the `LEFT` function, which is supported by some of these DBs:

[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx):

```
SELECT LEFT(column, 30) FROM table;
```

---

And of course you can use a column alias, like:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, 30) AS partial FROM table;
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, 30) AS partial FROM table;
```

Comment: Minor detail, SQL Server starts SUBSTRING at position 1.   0 will work, but you'll get 1 less character than expected

Comment: @Sparky Thank you, actually all of them use 1 as a starting character; with Oracle treating 0 as a 1.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql string start point is 1 so you should use

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, 30) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT LEFT(Data,30) FROM MyTable